# Why SQL datepart(ww,GETDATE()) returns current week + 1

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datepart

I am trying to get current week of the calendar. Let's assume today is **2022-03-14 12:00:00**.

I am using these 2:

```
select GETDATE() // returns 2022-03-14 12:00:00
select datepart(ww,GETDATE() //returns 12
```

But as per calendar 2022-03-14 12:00:00 should be 11st week.

From where is the difference coming from and how I can get basically current week?

Comment: See the long paragraph "iso_week datepart" on [DATEPART](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), The short version is use: `SELECT datepart(isoww,GETDATE())`

Comment: As the documentation [explains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#week-and-weekday-datepart-arguments), _the DATEPART return value depends on the value set by SET DATEFIRST`_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetDatePart(ww, ...) in SQL server is dependent on the set datefirst as [documented here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
You can use GetDatePart(isoww, getdate()) instead to get ISO Week Number.